# How to match a multiline regex in Clojure to parse a Groovy source file?

Tags: java, regex, groovy, clojure

I'm trying to run a Clojure regex on a Groovy source file to parse out the individual functions.

```
// gremlin.groovy

def warm_cache() {
  for (vertex in g.getVertices()) {
    vertex.getOutEdges()
  }
}

def clear() {
  g.clear()
}
```

This is the pattern I'm using in Clojure:

```
(def source (read-file "gremlin.groovy"))

(def pattern #"(?m)^def.*[^}]")   

(re-seq pattern source)
```

However, it's only grabbing the first line, not the multiline func.

Comment: Doesn't groovy have AST classes? I mean, there's already a groovy parser--why not use it?

Comment: You should never parse with regexps! Parse with *parsers*.

Comment: Removed the `antlr` tag since I didn't see anything related to it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your regex, not Clojure. You request to match `def`, then anything, then one char that is not equal to the closing brace. That char can be anywhere. What you want to achieve is this: `(?sm)def.*?^}`.

Comment: Thanks Marko. What I'm trying to say is to match def, then anything until and including a brace as the first char of a new line -- so the nested } are ignored since they are not the first char on a new line (this is in a very controlled env so it doesn't have to be super fancy).

Comment: I see. I don't think there's a way to express that in a regex, since `^` matches start of string only. It's just a special case that it can be used to match the start of a line, which is when the regex is used in non-multiline mode. You may try with matching an explicit newline char, but I found once that this is platform-specific and you'll need to match `\r\n` on Windows.

Comment: I thought Pattern.MULTILINE or (?m) tells Java/Clojure to accept the anchors ^ and $ to match at the start and end of each line (otherwise they only match at the start/end of the entire string).

Comment: Correct, my bad. Confused it with ?s. Updating answer to propose a solution.

Comment: isn't it `(?sm)def.*?^}` if you want the whole functions?

Comment: @tim_yates Almost right, you just need to escape that `}`. Updated the answer. EDIT: You don't, in fact :) Just the open brace needs escaping. I get constantly sidetracked with my own example where I switched to the open brace.

Answer (score 6):

As a demonstration of how you can grab the AST from the `GroovyRecognizer`, and avoid having the cope with trying to parse a language using regular expressions, you can do this in Groovy:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.*

def code = '''
// gremlin.groovy

def warm_cache() {
  for (vertex in g.getVertices()) {
    vertex.getOutEdges()
  }
}

def clear() {
  g.clear()
}
'''


def ast = new GroovyRecognizer( new GroovyLexer( new StringReader( code ) ).plumb() ).with { p ->
  p.compilationUnit()
  p.AST
}


while( ast ) {
  println ast.toStringTree()
  ast = ast.nextSibling
}
```

That prints out the AST for each [GroovySourceAST](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/antlr/GroovySourceAST.html) node in the AST, giving you (for this example):

```
 ( METHOD_DEF MODIFIERS TYPE warm_cache PARAMETERS ( { ( for ( in vertex ( ( ( . g getVertices ) ELIST ) ) ( { ( EXPR ( ( ( . vertex getOutEdges ) ELIST ) ) ) ) ) )
 ( METHOD_DEF MODIFIERS TYPE clear PARAMETERS ( { ( EXPR ( ( ( . g clear ) ELIST ) ) ) )
```

You should be able to do the same thing with Clojure's java interop and the groovy-all jar file

---

#### Edit

To get a bit more info, you just need to drill down into the AST and manipulate the input script a bit.  Changing the `while` loop in the above code to:

```
while( ast ) {
  if( ast.type == GroovyTokenTypes.METHOD_DEF ) {
    println """Lines $ast.line to $ast.lineLast
              |  Name:  $ast.firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.text
              |  Code:  ${code.split('\n')[ (ast.line-1)..<ast.lineLast ]*.trim().join( ' ' )}
              |   AST:  ${ast.toStringTree()}""".stripMargin()
  }
  ast = ast.nextSibling
}
```

prints out:

```
Lines 4 to 8
  Name:  warm_cache
  Code:  def warm_cache() { for (vertex in g.getVertices()) { vertex.getOutEdges() } }
   AST:   ( METHOD_DEF MODIFIERS TYPE warm_cache PARAMETERS ( { ( for ( in vertex ( ( ( . g getVertices ) ELIST ) ) ( { ( EXPR ( ( ( . vertex getOutEdges ) ELIST ) ) ) ) ) )
Lines 10 to 12
  Name:  clear
  Code:  def clear() { g.clear() }
   AST:   ( METHOD_DEF MODIFIERS TYPE clear PARAMETERS ( { ( EXPR ( ( ( . g clear ) ELIST ) ) ) )
```

Obviously, the `Code:` section is just the lines joined back together, so might not work if pasted back into groovy, but they give you an idea of the original code...

Comment: Thank you, Tim -- this is a truly great answer. And this is what I planned on doing. A few days ago, I asked in the Groovy User Group  how to do this but didn't get a response ( https://groups.google.com/d/topic/groovy-user/kvOv3t_O8ps/discussion ).

Comment: @espeed Ahh, sorry I missed that, I usually check the groovy-user mailing list and here, but didn't realise there was a Google Groups thing as well ;-)  Good luck with it!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer

```
(re-seq (Pattern/compile "(?m)^def.*[^}]" Pattern/MULTILINE) source)
```

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

> By default, the regular expressions ^ and $ ignore line terminators and only match at the beginning and the end, respectively, of the entire input sequence. If MULTILINE mode is activated then ^ matches at the beginning of input and after any line terminator except at the end of input. When in MULTILINE mode $ matches just before a line terminator or the end of the input sequence.

You need to be able to pass in

```
Pattern.MULTILINE
```

when the pattern is compiled. But there is no option for this on re-seq, so you'll probably need to drop down into Java interop to get this to work properly? Ideally, you really should be able to specify this in Clojure land... :(

UPDATE:
Actually, it's not all that bad. Instead of using the literal expression for a regex, just use Java interop for your pattern. Use `(re-seq (Pattern/compile "(?m)^def.*[^}]" Pattern/MULTILINE) source)` instead (assuming that you've imported java.util.regex.Pattern). I haven't tested this, but I think that will do the trick for you.